# Xslt gouping issue

Tags: xslt, grouping

I have an xml like below

```
<XYZ>
<Name>abc</Name>
<Year>1984</Year>
<Model>qwe</Model>
<Name>abc</Name>
<Year>1987</Year>
<Model>qwe</Model>
<Name>qweqr</Name>
<Year>1977</Year>
<Model>tryet</Model>
</XYZ>
```

Which needs to be transformed to 
    `<XYZ>
    <Name>abc</Name>
    <Year>1984</Year>
    <Year>1987</Year>
    <Model>qwe</Model>
    <Name>qweqr</Name>
    <Year>1977</Year>
    <Model>tryet</Model>
    </XYZ>`

Here Name can be considered as key

Comment: Which version of XSLT?

Comment: And how are you wanting the Model to be output? Do you want even Models grouped?

Comment: @user2317758 Please consider accepting answers by ticking them right if were helpful.

Answer (score 0):

With XSLT 1.0, this can be done using Muenchian Grouping with following XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:key name="names" match="Name" use="text()"/>
 <xsl:key name="models" match="Model" use="text()"/>
  <xsl:template match="XYZ">
  <XYZ> 
    <xsl:for-each select="//Name[generate-id()=generate-id(key('names',text())[1])]">
      <xsl:variable name="current" select="."/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//Name[.=$current]/following-sibling::Year[1]"/>
       <xsl:for-each select="//Name[.=$current]/following-sibling::Model[1]
                             [generate-id()=generate-id(key('models',text())[1])]">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
       </xsl:for-each>  
      </xsl:for-each>
    </XYZ>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Result:

```
<XYZ>
 <Name>abc</Name>
 <Year>1984</Year>
 <Year>1987</Year>
 <Model>qwe</Model>
 <Name>qweqr</Name>
 <Year>1977</Year>
 <Model>tryet</Model>
</XYZ>
```

The duplicate nodes for `Year` and `Model` are removed as only unique values are selected in the `xsl:for-each`:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//Name[generate-id()=generate-id(key('names',text())[1])]">
```

The unique `Name` is copied, then all years that have a preceding `Name` with the value of the current unique `Name`:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//Name[.=$current]/following-sibling::Year[1]"/>
```

Then, the corresponding unique `Model` nodes are copied with a second `xsl:for-each` selecting only unique following `Model` nodes:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//Name[.=$current]/following-sibling::Model[1]
                      [generate-id()=generate-id(key('models',text())[1])]">
```

As there are already many answers on Stackoverflow for XSLT grouping using the Muenchian method, I just recommend the detailed explanation in this article by Jeni Tennison http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.xml.

As additional reference for XSLT grouping you can have a look at http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N4486.html

**Update:** As suggested as comment, this won't work in case of duplicate `model` values for different `name` values. Following adjusted XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8 indent="yes" />
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:key name="names" match="Name" use="text()"/>
  <xsl:template match="XYZ">
    <XYZ> 
      <xsl:for-each select="//Name[generate-id()=generate-id(key('names',text())[1])]">
        <xsl:variable name="current" select="."/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//Name[.=$current]/following-sibling::Year[1]"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="//Name[.=$current]/following-sibling::Model[1]
                              [not(.= preceding-sibling::Name[.=$current]
                              /preceding-sibling::Name[.=$current]
                              /following-sibling::Model)]">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>  
      </xsl:for-each>
    </XYZ>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

works for the example XML provided in OP as well as the example XML suggested in the comment - only unique `name` values with optional multiple years and unique `model` values for a `name`, but the same `model` can also be listed for a different `name`.

Comment: I don't think that this code will work for all scenarios, as the grouping on `Model` is done on all `Model`s in the document with same value. Try this XML input: `<XYZ>
 <Name>abc</Name>
 <Year>1987</Year>
 <Model>qwe</Model>
 <Name>qweqr</Name>
 <Year>1977</Year>
 <Model>qwe</Model>
</XYZ>`

Comment: @LingamurthyCS Thanks for considering this. Just adjusted with a second version in case of duplicate `Model` values for different `Name` values. But I've to admit that it would be easier if OP would mention which values can have duplicates as the example provided in OP is not absolutely clear.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this stylesheet, which uses keys to select `Year` and `Model`(groups the Models too based on their Name and then with their value) based on their preceding `Name`(after grouping Names):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="Name" match="Name" use="."/>
<xsl:key name="Year" match="Year" use="preceding::Name[1]"/>
<xsl:key name="Model" match="Model" use="preceding::Name[1]"/>

<xsl:template match="XYZ">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="Name[count(. | key('Name', .)[1]) = 1]">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="key('Year', .)"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="key('Model', .)[not(. = preceding::Model[preceding::Name[1] = current()])]"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```